# How to provide SQL subquery in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What is the best practice to convert Sub Query into LINQ,
for example I use this following query :

```
select VerID = (select top 1 x.INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID from
                  CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION x where a.RECID = x.CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR 
                  order by x.VERSIONDATETIME desc), 
       c.LINENUM, c.RECID, * 
from CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR a inner join CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS c 
      on a.PACKINGSLIPID = c.PACKINGSLIPID
```

Answer (score 1):

I simulated you database with classes to get the syntax correct.  Make modifications as necessary.  There is no best method.  Some people like using Where instead of joins.  I like joins.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSIONs> CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION = new List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSIONs>();
            List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOURs> CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR = new List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOURs>();
            List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANSs> CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS = new List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANSs>();

            var VerId = (from vId in CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION
                         join slipId in CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR on vId.INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID equals slipId.RECID
                         join cId in CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS on vId.INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID equals cId.PACKINGSLIPID
                         select new { vid = vId, slipId = slipId, cId = cId })
                         .GroupBy(x => x.vid.VERSIONDATETIME)
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                         .FirstOrDefault()
                         .Select(x => new { linenum = x.cId.LINENUM, recid = x.cId.RECID })
                         .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSIONs
    {
        public int INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID { get; set; }
        public DateTime VERSIONDATETIME { get; set; }
    }
    public class CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOURs
    {
        public int RECID { get; set; }
        public int PACKINGSLIPID { get; set; }
    }
    public class CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANSs
    {
        public int PACKINGSLIPID { get; set; }
        public int LINENUM { get; set; }
        public int RECID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I had misinterpreted your query: it returns first record of `linenum` & `recid`, but the OP has `*` in `SELECT` indicating he want to select all `CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR` columns, then returns all `LINENUM` +  `RECID` and only returns single record of `INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID`.

Comment: I can't tell what * means in this case.  It could be one property or 100 properties.  The original selected top 1 time and again I can't tell if this is one row or many rows.  I did the best I could with the amount of info posted.

Comment: I modified code to group by date so you get all the rows for the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your query and I am assuming it is a typo: `a.RECID = x.CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR` because `CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR` is the collection name. Therefore, I used `SomeId` instead. But this should give you the idea:

Do a subquery within the projection. You will also need to order by descending and then take the first record-this will be like `top 1`. Here is the query:

```
var query = from a in CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR
            join c in CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS on a.PACKINGSLIPID equals c.PACKINGSLIPID
            select new
            {
                VerID = (from x in CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION
                         where a.RECID == x.SomeId select x)
                         .OrderByDescending(o => o.VERSIONDATETIME)
                         .First().INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID,
                c.LINENUM,
                c.RECID
            };
```

You can test it with the following collections:

```
var CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR = new List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR> { new CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR { PACKINGSLIPID = 1, RECID = 1 },
        new CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR { PACKINGSLIPID = 2, RECID = 2 }};
        var CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS = new List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS>
        {
            new CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS { LINENUM = 1, RECID = 1, PACKINGSLIPID = 1 }
        };
        var CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION = new List<CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION>
        {
            new CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION { INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID = 1, SomeId = 1, VERSIONDATETIME = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) },
            new CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION { INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID = 2, SomeId = 1, VERSIONDATETIME = DateTime.Today }
        };
```

It will be the same query if you use a `DbSet<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have those setup:

```
public class TBL_CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION
{
    public int CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION_ID { get; set; }
    public int INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID { get; set; }
    public DateTime VERSIONDATETIME { get; set; }
}
public class TBL_CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR
{
    public int RECID { get; set; }
    public int PACKINGSLIPID { get; set; }
}
public class TBL_CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS
{
    public int PACKINGSLIPID { get; set; }
    public int LINENUM { get; set; }
    public int RECID { get; set; }
}

var CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION = new List<TBL_CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION>();
var CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR = new List<TBL_CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR>();
var CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS = new List<TBL_CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS>();
```

Then you can setting up the combined query as given in example below (assumed `CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION_ID` is the identity key which used in comparison between `CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR` & `CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS`):

```
var query = (from a in CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR
             join c in CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS
             on a.PACKINGSLIPID equals c.PACKINGSLIPID
             select new {
                 VerID = (from x in CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION
                          where a.RECID == x.CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION_ID // should be an identity column/primary key to compare with
                          orderby x.VERSIONDATETIME descending
                          select x).FirstOrDefault().INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID,
                 c.LINENUM,
                 c.RECID
             }).ToList();
```

Note that your query includes `*` at the end of `SELECT` statement which may indicate the query will return all records from both tables involved in `join` clause. If you want to return entire records of `CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR` only but not return all `CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS`, include `a` into the `select new` statement (incorporates SQL usage of `a.*`):

```
select new {
    VerID = (from x in CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION
             where a.RECID == x.CUSTPACKINGSLIPVERSION_ID // should be an identity column/primary key to compare with
             orderby x.VERSIONDATETIME descending
             select x).FirstOrDefault().INTERNALPACKINGSLIPID,
    c.LINENUM,
    c.RECID,
    a // used if you want to return all records from CUSTPACKINGSLIPJOUR
}).ToList();
```